# python unable to unpack returned values from Octave function

Tags: python, function, octave, return-value, oct2py

I have a function called doFFT.m in Octave, defined as:

```
function [Rx1,Rx2,fbins]=doFFT(file)
```

this function runs as expected returning 3 row vectors.

In Python, I have oct2py imported,

```
from oct2py import octave
```

and I call this Octave function via:

```
RX1,RX2,fbins=octave.doFFT(file)
```

I get an error that says "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)"

As a test I redefined the function in Octave to only return 1 value, and instead called it in Python as :

```
RX1=octave.doFFT(file)
```

and this worked fine.

So, the issue seems to be with having Python understand the return format from Octave.
I've tried calling the function as

```
[RX1, RX2, fbins]=octave.doFFT(file)
(RX1, RX2, fbins)=octave.doFFT(file)
```

for example, but still get either the same error.

How do I format the function call or the output from Octave, so that Python "understands" that there are 3 items being returned?

Comment: Try this: *response=octave.doFFT(file); print(type(response))* That should give you a clue about what's happening. Is there no documentation for the doFFT function?

Comment: @Lancelot Thank you.  the doFFT function is my own function -- I know exactly what it returns.  It returns 3 row vectors.  It works fine in Octave.  It is only the interface with Python where I'm having trouble, where somehow python is interpreting these 3 vectors as 1.  So, it is either 1) how I'm calling the function , 2) or how I must modify the returned values from the function so that python sees them as 3 vectors and not 1.

Comment: What does Python think the return type is?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.  I think I found out what I need to do.  It is not clear to me, but it seems the octave python bridge requires me to explicitly convey the expected number of return values.    If I do , RX1,RX2,fbins=octave.doFFT(file,nout=3), that seems to work.

Comment: @jrive yes that is correct. See [oct2py's documentation](https://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/source/api.html) for more details. This question is a near duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394393/oct2py-only-returning-the-first-output-argument) but I think is phrased sufficiently differently to merit not being closed as a duplicate. Please feel free to answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Also, for a more general explanation (e.g. addressing @LancelotduLac 's comment); the reason the number of output arguments cannot be inferred and need to be stated explicitly, is because sometimes matlab/octave functions behave differently based on the expected number of arguments. So you cannot simply get a 1x3 numpy array out and assume the 3 values correspond to that function having being called with 3 output arguments.

Answer (score 0):

the `oct2py` python bridge requires that the expected number of returned values to be explicitly expressed in the function call, for eg.

```
RX1,RX2,fbins=octave.doFFT(samples, nout=3)
```

specifies that the function returns 3 values (or numpy arrays in this case).
When a function doesn't return anything, it must be called indicating that it returns 0 arguments, ie:

```
octave.foobar(in_arg, nout=0).
```

Thank you to @Tasos Papastlyianou for linking the oct2py's documentation in his comment.